# Method 'DUMPSETSET_GET_ENTITYSET' not implemented in data provider class

Tags: sap-gateway

I created a function module and gateway service that reads data from SNAP_BEG table which is stores DUMP issues. There is no any error except that.

When I try to use link as /DumpsetSet I get 
"Method 'DUMPSETSET_GET_ENTITYSET' not implemented in data provider class"

I found that how to redefine implementation but what code should I write in it? I cant find an example for this. Function module code is.

```
SELECT * FROM SNAP_BEG INTO TABLE ET_SNAP_BEG.
```

Or I just need to use something else?
What type of link should I use. I got one more project someoneelse done and I cant see difference in implementation from mine.

Edit: I can get firs record that program find by /DumpsetSet('username'). But it is not giving me all datas anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you map the GetEntitySet to a data source from SEGW - SAP Gateway Service Builder, under the Service Implementation part. After this operation you should generate runtime objects.

There is a good blog for this, [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/26/step-by-step-guide-to-build-an-odata-service-based-on-rfcs-part-1/).